# Simple, online collaborative database

Tags: tool-request

I would like to launch an online collaborative database (< 100 MB, most likely < 10 MB). I'll use either MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL.

I need a platform that would allow people to submit pull requests to improve the database, and the pull requests should be readable. Is there such platforms? Perhaps GitHub can be used for that purpose (unsure how readable diff of large SQL dumps would be)?

I am aware of [dat](http://dat-data.com/) but I don't want to have to host the repository. I am also aware of DataHub (1) but it looks like a [prototype](http://datahub.csail.mit.edu/www/) only.

---

(1) Bhardwaj, Anant, et al. "[Datahub: Collaborative data science & dataset version management at scale.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9226944536687783316&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" arXiv preprint arXiv:1409.0798 (2014).

Comment: This discussion may be of interest - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/748/1511

Comment: Though hideously ugly, storing each record in a separate file may do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232). I am not sure if it solve all your issues, but it is a hosted solution where you can use their API to update the table from whenever you want. It is perfect for collaboration. And if I am wrong they have something like attributions to identify who modify the data and when.

Details about their API and sample codes here: [link](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code)